# EEG electrode cluster selection

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, methodology, eeg, neuroimaging, analysis

Is there a good review paper on electrode selection in EEG analysis to avoid the problem of double dipping (Kilner, 2013)? This is a well documented issue in neuroimaging ([Kriegeskorte et al, 2009](http://individual.utoronto.ca/MSL/papers/Kriegeskorte_09_Circular_analysis.pdf); [Vul et al., 2009](http://pages.ucsd.edu/~cmckenzie/Vuletal2009Perspectives.pdf)), but I wanted to find a deeper exploration of the approaches to deal with this with experiments involving high density EEG caps and selection of electrodes (clusters of electrodes) of interest.